# API PHP with React Native send image and text in server

Tags: php, react-native

I need to upload 2 description and the image I take from the camera, but the camera, but I get an error, does anyone know where the error is?

this is the react native code:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View,Text,StyleSheet,TextInput,TouchableOpacity,Image} from 'react-native';

import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-picker';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-material-dropdown';

const options={
    title:'select a photo',
    takePhotoButtonTitle:'Take a Photo',
    chooseFrmoLibraryButtonTitle:'Choose from Gallery',
    quality:1
};


class InputUsers extends Component{

//constructor have a state that conatains the properties that will recieve the values from Text Inputes
    constructor(props){
       super(props)
        this.state = {
            TextInputName:'',
            iamgeSource: null,
            data: [
                    {
                        value: 'Computadoras encendidas',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'Puerta Abierta',
                    },
              {
                        value: 'llaves perdidas',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'Retraso de personal',
                    },
              {
                        value: 'alarmas desactivadas',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'personal no reconocido',
                    },
              {
                        value: 'Agresion',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'Aulas desordenadas',
                    },
              {
                        value: 'No hay empleados',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'No llego compa;ero',
                    },
              {
                        value: 'Fugas de gas',
                    },
                    {
                        value: 'Puerta esta cerrada',
                    },
                ],
        }
    }

    selectPhoto(){
        ImagePicker.launchCamera(options, (response) => {
            console.log('Response = ', response);

            if (response.didCancel) {
              console.log('User cancelled image picker');
            }
            else if (response.error) {
              console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
            }
            else {
              let source = { uri: response.uri };
              this.setState({
                iamgeSource: source
              });
            }
          });
    }

//arrow function that will fire when press on save button to save data in database via API
    InsertUser = ()=>{
        //constant varaibles that equal propertes in state
        const {TextInputName} = this.state;
        const {iamgeSource} = this.state;

        const formData = new FormData();
        //Add your input data
        formData.append('name', TextInputName);

        //Add your photo
        //this, retrive the file extension of your photo
        const uriPart = iamgeSource.uri.split('.');
        const fileExtension = uriPart[uriPart.length - 1];

        formData.append('photo', {
            uri: iamgeSource.uri,
            name: 'photo.${fileExtension}',
            type: 'image/${fileExtension}'
        });

        //API that use fetch to input data to database via backend php script
        fetch('http://192.168.0.4/conex/subirimagen.php',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
              },
              body: formData
          })
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((responseJson) => {
           // return responseJson
             alert(responseJson);
             this.props.navigation.navigate('seconde');
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
              });

       //alert('Pressed!!');
        }


    render(){
        return(
            <View style ={styles.container}>
                <TextInput
                // value = {this.TextInputName}
                 placeholder = 'Descripcion del incidente'
                 onChangeText = {TextInputValue=>this.setState({TextInputName:TextInputValue}) }
                 underlineColorAndroid = 'transparent'
                 style = {styles.TextInputStyle}
                />




                <Image style={styles.image}
                    source={this.state.iamgeSource != null ? this.state.iamgeSource : require('./image/blogSix.png')}
                />

                <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.TouchableOpacityStyle} onPress={this.selectPhoto.bind(this)}>
                    <Text style = {styles.TextStyle}>Seleccione la foto</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity = {.4} style = {styles.TouchableOpacityStyle} onPress={this.InsertUser}>
                    <Text style = {styles.TextStyle}>Enviar incidente</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>



            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create ({
    container : {
        alignItems:'center',
        flex:1,
        marginTop:5,
        backgroundColor:'#fff'
    },

    TextInputStyle :{
        textAlign:'center',
        marginBottom:7,
        width:'90%',
        height:40,
        borderWidth:1,
        borderRadius:5,
        borderColor:'#FF5722'
    },

    TextInputStyle2 :{
        textAlign:'center',
        marginBottom:7,
        marginTop:20,
        width:'90%',
        height:40,
        borderWidth:1,
        borderRadius:5,
        borderColor:'#FF5722'
    },

    TextStyle : {
        color:'#fff',
        textAlign:'center'
    },

    TouchableOpacityStyle:{
        paddingTop:10,
        paddingBottom:10,
        marginTop:20,
        borderRadius:5,
        marginBottom:7,
        width:'90%',
        backgroundColor:'#00BCD4'
    },

    button:{
        width:250,
        height:50,
        backgroundColor:"#330066"
    },

    text:{
        color:'white',
        fontSize:30,
        textAlign:'center'
    },

    textInput2: {
      textAlign:'center',
      marginBottom:7,
      marginTop:20,
      width:'90%',
      height:40,
      borderWidth:1,
      borderRadius:5,
      borderColor:'#FF5722',
      paddingBottom:25,

    },

    image:{
        width:200,
        height:200,
        marginTop:30
    }



});

export default InputUsers;
```

this is the php script

```
 <?php
  // Create database connection
  $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "image_upload");

  // Initialize message variable
  $msg = "";

  $json = file_get_contents('php://input');

   // decoding the received JSON and store into $obj variable.
   $obj = json_decode($json,true);


  // If upload button is clicked ...
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    // Get image name
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    // Get text
    $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);

    // image file directory
    $target = "images/".basename($image);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text) VALUES ('$image', '$image_text')";
    // execute query
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
    }else{
        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
    }
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
?>
```

i need to send all data from app to php server including the image that user uploaded when hit save button , any Help ?

pls help me.